# What is the equivalent method of VectorWritable.addTo in mahout 0.5 in mahout 0.7?

Tags: java, hadoop, mahout, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender

I found the code for the book mahout in action is missing method. Mahout 0.7 seems do not have addTo. What is the equivalent? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://search-lucene.com/m/VOQb42qY6Zw1/addTo&subj=removal+of+addTo+in+vectors

=>  The replacement of addTo() with .assign(..., Functions.PLUS)